# Why did't PHP require throw error?

Tags: php, error-handling, require

So I hear that require will produce a fatal error (E_COMPILE_ERROR) and stop the script.

It did stop the script and I got blank page. But I checked error log and found no error. (Nginx)

I tried to require "../lib/Smarty.class.php" but I didn't upload lib folder. I was expecting to see fatal error but there wasn't any.

Why?

I have

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

as well in my script.

Anything that I missed?

Comment: set display_errors to 1, error_reporting(-1), and use set_error_handler with a handler function which throws ErrorException and second param still -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use to set display errors to 1 then on error_reporting...

```
    // change settings for error handler to show errors
    // $this setup is used for checking errors for development to be shown.... 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //then if you want to have error handler use
   error_log(); //to log your errors within a specify location..
```

Comment: **ALTHOUGH** Your server might forbid inline display_errors settings. In that case, contact your admin and ask for help. (happened to me a couple of times)

Comment: Yes thats rights, sometimes web server admins don`t accept inline editing of these for some security purposes..

Answer (score 0):

> Anything that I missed?

The [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) setting.

Comment: I was referring to the blank page, looks like he expected to see the error on screen and *then* checked the logs. But you are right, both settings are relevant to the question.

Comment: If hes just referring to showing the error on the blank page .He`s definitely right..